# C++ Hello World: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, gcc

when I try to compile a simple hello world code I get some architecture error from gcc

$ vim test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

$ gcc test.cpp -o test.o

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in ccyEpFri.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccyEpFri.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccyEpFri.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))", referenced from:
      _main in ccyEpFri.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccyEpFri.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccyEpFri.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The gcc I have is here: /usr/local/bin/gcc

$ gcc --version

```
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

System setup: `Mac OSX yosemit 10.10.2`
GCC from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/

My original gcc 4.2 (the default on mac) was giving me `couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.1.0'` That's why I went for http://hpc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Just use g++ instead of gcc

Comment: $ g++ test.cpp -o test.o
ld: entry point (start) undefined.  Usually in crt1.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @MortezaShahriariNia you on windows OS? Maybe you don't have the 64bit version of MinGW installed?

Comment: What operating system? How did you get and installed your GCC? Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: I'm running on OSX yosemite. I got the compiler from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You should edit your question to improve it, not add some comment!

Comment: As I see, GCC is manually compiled. Have you compiled libstdc++ too? Is it available at default linker path? If not, you should use line like:
$ g++ test.cpp -o test -L/path/to/dir-with-libstdc++.so

Comment: @Vadim Prozorov: no, the OP downloaded some binary tarball....

Comment: Then the last chance I see is to specify `-L/usr/local/lib`. And manually compile GCC if this way failed.

Comment: Perhaps you have some [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)? Then you could use it (at least to compile [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) from source)

Comment: I do have CLang as part of xcode. due to some dependency issues it is suggested to stick to gcc.

Comment: Then you probably should compile GCC from source.

Answer (score 2):

Use g++ instead of gcc.

g++ is a *nix-based C++ compiler. gcc is a compiler for C, C++, Objective-C, Fortran, Java, Ada, and Go. The libraries used are different. Your code will work with g++ not gcc.

Comment: Same error 

`$ g++   test.cpp -o mytestprog`
ld: entry point (start) undefined.  Usually in crt1.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: no, just error and stops. no file created or modified

Answer (score 1):

You should compile with

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g  test.cpp -o mytestprog
```

then run `./mytestprog` and use `gdb` for debugging it.

If that command does not work, you might add `-v` after `g++` (to be shown what is happening), and it would be a symptom that your `g++` was wrongly configured or installed. Of course, do a `which g++` to be sure that the `g++` is the one you want.

Read my hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28663720/841108) about compiling your GCC. I believe that the binaries you've got from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ do not fit your operating system. I would suggest to *carefully* build, compile and install, GCC from its source code (downloadable via these [mirrors](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html)). It probably is not very easy (for newbies). Be sure to build *outside* of the source tree. Read *carefully* the [install](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) instructions.

Comment: Same error

$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -g  test.cpp -o mytestprog
    ld: entry point (start) undefined.  Usually in crt1.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status