# g++: link to non-standard /usr/local

Tags: macos, unix, gcc, installation, g++

I have an OSX 10.7 computer with a non-administrator account, and was attempting to install the pre-compiled versions of gcc and g++ found [here](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/). I've attempted to use the answers presented [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726993/g-how-to-specify-preference-of-library-path/2727033#2727033/) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663670/modify-g-library-path) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905661/on-mac-g-fails-to-search-usr-local-include-and-usr-local-lib-by-default/) (three different links) to compile some code with g++, to confusing avail. I have a folder structure like this:

```
~/code/:
    usr/:
        local/:
            bin/ (3.6MB)
            include/ (8.6MB)
            lib/ (51MB)
            libexec/ (49MB)
            share/ (16MB)
    c++/:
        source/ (contains .cpp files)
```

g++ -v returns this:

```
code USER$ usr/local/bin/g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=usr/local/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/    x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.1/configure --enable-languages=fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.1 (GCC)
```

An attempt at compiling a file that "#include"s only iostream:

```
$ usr/local/bin/g++ c++/source/test.cpp -o ex6
In file included from     /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/postypes.h:42:0,
             from /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/iosfwd:42,
             from /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/ios:39,
             from /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/ostream:40,
             from /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/iostream:40,
             from c++/source/ex6.cpp:1:
/Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/cwchar:46:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I tried compiling with some flags recommended in one of the links mentioned, like this: (with all combinations of "usr/" to "usr/local/include/" and "usr/" to "/usr/local/lib" giving the same result (which is also the same as using no flags).

```
$ /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/g++ source/ex6.cpp -I/Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/include/ -L/Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/lib/In file included from /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/postypes.h:42:0,
             from /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/iosfwd:42,
             from /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/ios:39,
             from /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/ostream:40,
             from /Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/iostream:40,
             from source/ex6.cpp:1:
/Users/USERNAME/code/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/cwchar:46:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

In short, I'm having trouble understanding what the answers in the links provided are saying to do. I saw reference to a specs file, which I could find no specific information for, and "-Wl,-rpath,$(DEFAULT_LIB_INSTALL_PATH)", for which I couldn't figure out what I was supposed to substitute for "DEFAULT_LIB_INSTALL_PATH".

What should I do to point the downloaded g++ compiler to its own files without placing them in their default location, as I do not have administrative capabilities on this account?

I will provide any information as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have required header files. You need to install `Command Line Tools` from [Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com) site (free registration needed). The problem is that you don't have administrator account. I suggest that you ask the administrator to install the tools for you. If it is not possible you could try to extract the contents of downloaded package (`DevSDK.pkg`) to your local directory ([Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com) can do that) and pass the path with the missing headers to your compiler. I haven't tried that though.

Comment: I actually have tried that (using Pacifist, even). I can't remember why, but it didn't work. I tried using a guide that used tar to unzip the pkg files, and I think that there was something about the file structure that I didn't know how to deal with. I'll check.

Comment: I can't find the tutorial that I tried to use. I'm fairly certain that it was on stackoverflow, though.

Comment: It is easy. Just use Pacifist to extract `usr/include` folder with libc headers to your local folder. Then add `-I/path/to/extracted/include` to compiler.

Comment: I just tried that, and it gave the same message. The exact command that I used is `$ ../usr/local/bin/g++ -I../include source/ex6.cpp`. I, then, tried copying the files within include to the downloaded g++ directory (I backed it up before that), without replacing the only conflicting folder: "c++". Same message. I tried replacing "c++". Same message. I don't entirely understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: If you have exactly the same error message as before, complaining about missing `wchar.h` file, make sure the file is in the folder you copied from downloaded package. Also make sure you pass the file path to the compiler

Comment: I made sure before I moved the folder that `wchar.h` was there. What do you mean by "pass the file path to the compiler? Would you mind typing out the command that I should use, based on the command in my above comment and the file structure that I have provided, with `include` being at `code/include/`.

Comment: I will try that, but how is that path different from `../include` when in the `c++` folder?